# Get an array reference from an object

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, google-chrome

I have a javascript code (someone has done it) which gets data from a server side (code not available).

jxr['hilites'] = $.get(url_interface + "&do=hilites&page=" + page, function(json) {
}

[image]

When I debug the code in Chrome. I see that the object json has another object called 2, which further contains arrays of integer type.

My questions: 
1. Is 2 the name of the object or the position? If position then why it does not show position 0 and 1?
2. If it is a name I wonder how is it possible to name it with a number. Any example link?

I am sorry for asking a very basic question. I will be thankful for the reply.

Comment: It's the name, not the index.  You can access it with `json["2"]["2_1"][0]` (for example)

Comment: i don't think "Debug JQuery code" is a good title… :)

Comment: @Archer if only SO had a "flag as answer" button.

Comment: I don't like putting answers when they're so simple, but on this occasion you've convinced me :D

Comment: @Archer: Can you please let me know an example. How to create such json lets say in C#. I need it urgently. Thanks Thanks

Comment: If you do not want this format on the client, than the server needs to change. Plain and simple. URGENT requests mean nothing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`2` is the name of the property. Objects do not have names, the closest they come is to have a variable or property (which will have an identifier) which references them.

Even in an array, the position is just an artifact of arrays being a type of object that gives special significance to properties with names that are integers.

You can have sparse arrays:

```
var foo = [];
foo.push("data");
foo.push("data");
foo.push("data");
delete foo[1];
console.log("Length: " , foo.length);
console.log("Array: " , foo);
console.log("0" in foo, "1" in foo, "2" in foo);

Length:  3
Array:  [ 'data', , 'data' ]
true false true
```

Comment: Can you please write an example for above question object where it creates above json object. Thanks

Comment: It's the same as any other property name that isn't a valid identifier. Use a string. `var foo = { "2": {/* more data in this object*/} }`

Comment: Ok. What is equivalent of foo in c#? I mean how to create such object in c#

Comment: I have no idea how you create a variable in c#, I've never used the language.

Comment: @mrd the closest you will get to a JS object in C# is an [ExpandoObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.expandoobject(v=vs.110).aspx) (this is effectively just a wrapper around a dictionary).